# HIbernate+JPA Composite Key problem: generating select sql with wrong columns

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa

Here is my sample codes.

PrimaryKey Class:

```
public class ReplAreaElemDataCompositeKey implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    
private int imageElementID; 
private int variableID;

public ReplAreaElemDataCompositeKey() {
    super();
}

/**
 * @param imageElementID
 * @param variableID
 */
public ReplAreaElemDataCompositeKey(int imageElementID, int variableID) {
    super();
    this.imageElementID = imageElementID;
    this.variableID = variableID;
}

/**
 * Method to getImageElementID
 *
 * @return the imageElementID
 */

public int getImageElementID() {
    return imageElementID;
}

/**
 * Method to setImageElementID
 *
 * @param imageElementID the imageElementID to set
 */
public void setImageElementID(int imageElementID) {
    this.imageElementID = imageElementID;
}

/**
 * Method to getVariableID
 *
 * @return the variableID
 */

public int getVariableID() {
    return variableID;
}

/**
 * Method to setVariableID
 *
 * @param variableID the variableID to set
 */
public void setVariableID(int variableID) {
    this.variableID = variableID;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (int) imageElementID;
    hash += (int) variableID;
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    if (!(object instanceof ReplAreaElemDataCompositeKey)) {
        return false;
    }
    ReplAreaElemDataCompositeKey other = (ReplAreaElemDataCompositeKey) object;
    if (this.imageElementID != other.getImageElementID()) {
        return false;
    }
    if (this.variableID != other.getVariableID()) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
}
```

class using PrimaryKey

```
@Entity
@IdClass(ReplAreaElemDataCompositeKey.class)
public class ReplAreaElemDataEntity {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "IMAGE_ELEM_NBR", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private int imageElementID;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "REPL_VAR_NBR", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private int variableID;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="IMAGE_ELEM_NBR")
    private ImageElementEntity imageElementEntity;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="REPL_VAR_NBR")
    private ReplVariableEntity replVariableEntity;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "REPL_AREA_DATA")
    private String variableData;

    /**
     * Method to getImageElementID
     *
     * @return the imageElementID
     */

    public int getImageElementID() {
        return imageElementID;
    }

    /**
     * Method to setImageElementID
     *
     * @param imageElementID the imageElementID to set
     */
    public void setImageElementID(int imageElementID) {
        this.imageElementID = imageElementID;
    }

    /**
     * Method to getVariableID
     *
     * @return the variableID
     */

    public int getVariableID() {
        return variableID;
    }

    /**
     * Method to setVariableID
     *
     * @param variableID the variableID to set
     */
    public void setVariableID(int variableID) {
        this.variableID = variableID;
    }

    /**
     * Method to getImageElementEntity
     *
     * @return the imageElementEntity
     */

    public ImageElementEntity getImageElementEntity() {
        return imageElementEntity;
    }

    /**
     * Method to setImageElementEntity
     *
     * @param imageElementEntity the imageElementEntity to set
     */
    public void setImageElementEntity(ImageElementEntity imageElementEntity) {
        this.imageElementEntity = imageElementEntity;
    }

    /**
     * Method to getReplVariableEntity
     *
     * @return the replVariableEntity
     */

    public ReplVariableEntity getReplVariableEntity() {
        return replVariableEntity;
    }

    /**
     * Method to setReplVariableEntity
     *
     * @param replVariableEntity the replVariableEntity to set
     */
    public void setReplVariableEntity(ReplVariableEntity replVariableEntity) {
        this.replVariableEntity = replVariableEntity;
    }

    /**
     * Method to getVariableData
     *
     * @return the variableData
     */

    public String getVariableData() {
        return variableData;
    }

    /**
     * Method to setVariableData
     *
     * @param variableData the variableData to set
     */
    public void setVariableData(String variableData) {
        this.variableData = variableData;
    }   
}
```

SQL Query generating like this:

```
SELECT replareael0_.IMAGE_ELEM_NBR AS IMAGE4_2_,
  replareael0_.imageElementID      AS imageEle1_2_,
  replareael0_.variableID          AS variableID2_,
  replareael0_.imageElementID      AS imageEle1_2_1_,
  replareael0_.variableID          AS variableID2_1_,
  replareael0_.IMAGE_ELEM_NBR      AS IMAGE4_2_1_
 ...
 ...
from ...
```

some fields are repeating and field names are like property names means not db column name.

Answer (score 2):

The JPA wiki book explains pretty well how to map this kind of relation (a

> JPA 1.0 requires that all `@Id`
>   mappings be Basic mappings, so if your
>   Id comes from a foreign key column
>   through a `OneToOne` or `ManyToOne`
>   mapping, you must also define a `Basic`
>   `@Id` mapping for the foreign key
>   column. The reason for this is in part
>   that the Id must be a simple object
>   for identity and caching purposes, and
>   for use in the `IdClass` or the
>   `EntityManager` `find()` API.
>
> Because you now have two mappings for
>   the same foreign key column **you must
>   define which one will be written to
>   the database (it must be the `Basic`
>   one), so the `OneToOne` or `ManyToOne`
>   foreign key must be defined to be
>   read-only. This is done through
>   setting the `JoinColumn` attributes
>   `insertable` and `updatable` to `false`, or
>   by using the `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`
>   instead of the `@JoinColumn`**.
>
> A side effect of having two mappings
>   for the same column is that you now
>   have to keep the two in synch. This is
>   typically done through having the set
>   method for the `OneToOne` attribute also
>   set the Basic attribute value to the
>   target object's id. This can become
>   very complicated if the target
>   object's primary key is a
>   `GeneratedValue`, in this case you must
>   ensure that the target object's id has
>   been assigned before relating the two
>   objects.

So try the following instead:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(ReplAreaElemDataCompositeKey.class)
public class ReplAreaElemDataEntity {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "IMAGE_ELEM_NBR")
    private int imageElementID;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "REPL_VAR_NBR")
    private int variableID;

    @ManyToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="IMAGE_ELEM_NBR")
    private ImageElementEntity imageElementEntity;

    @ManyToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="REPL_VAR_NBR")
    private ReplVariableEntity replVariableEntity;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "REPL_AREA_DATA")
    private String variableData;

    ...
}
```

#### Resource

- JPA Wiki Book

  - [Primary Keys through OneToOne Relationships](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Primary_Keys_through_OneToOne_Relationships)